# css: multiple divs prevent line break instead do scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have the following example: [enter link description here](http://%20http://jsfiddle.net/m1cywotg/)

I want to archive that the divs with the class 'following' will be displayed in one line with the red 'left' container. In the example there is a line break after the third blue container.
If there are two many following blue items, i want to have a horizontal scrollbar instead of the line break.
The second row in this example is ok, because it has not enough blue containers.

```css
  .container {
        width:600px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid;
    }
    
    .row {
       clear: both;
    }
    
    .left {
        width: 200px;
        height:50px;
        background:red;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .following {
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background: blue;
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
      <div class="following"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I've updated it to use a flex layout instead.

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.left {
    width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.following {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

is this the answer of your question?

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    overflow: auto;
}

.row {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -moz-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.left {
    min-width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.following {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
  <div class="following"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much